# Apex Charts Custom tooltip: How to alter alignment of seriesName in tooltip?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am trying to get the series name aligned to center, beside the color in the tooltip, as the value in my tooltip has a couple of lines of data. The series name is by default aligned bottom-left corner.
 How to align series name to center beside the color?  
Please view the attached image for a clear understanding of my question.

Ignore series data values in the code below

```
    series: [
      { name: 'Low (0 - 25%)', data: [rep_estval_low[1], 200000, 1000000, 500000, 400000, 600000], labels: rep_label_low.slice(1, 7) },
      { name: 'Medium (50%)', data: [600000, 120000, 650000, 750000, 110000, 900000], labels: rep_label_med.slice(1, 7) },
      { name: 'High (75 - 100%)', data: [rep_estval_high[1], 900000, 115000, 350000, 650000, 120000], labels: rep_label_high.slice(1, 7) }
    ],
    
    tooltip: {
         y: {
        formatter: function (value, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
          var label = w.config.series[seriesIndex].labels[dataPointIndex];
          var labelTooltip = label.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
          return labelTooltip;
        }
     }
    },
    xaxis: {
    categories: ['<0 Days', '0-30 Days', '31-60 Days', '61-90 Days', '91-180 Days', '>180 Days'],
    labels: { show: true }},
```

[image: Tooltip image]